# How to append form data to the same page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I currently have two forms that appear when two different buttons are clicked. So, when button a is clicked, then button b appears and button a is still on the screen.  I would like it so when the  page loads, that both buttons are side by side. Also, when I submit the form data for form A it works and goes to the top left corner of the screen where I want it, but when I submit form B, the data from form B appears under the last input field when I click button A to show button A's form. I would like for when I submit form b, it's data to appear under from a's already added data to the web page please, not under a's form when I click button a to input form data into form a's input field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
<div id="formData" >
<?php
#FOR THE DRIVERS ONLY 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    $_SESSION['inputs'] = array();
}
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['age'])  && !empty($_POST['departLoc']) 
    && !empty($_POST['arriveLoc']) && !empty($_POST['departDate'])  && !empty($_POST['returnDate']) 
    &&  !empty($_POST['desiredNum'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['inputs'])) {
        // initialize the saved input session variable the first time
        $_SESSION['inputs'] = array();
    }
    $_SESSION['inputs'][] = $_POST;
    foreach ($_SESSION['inputs'] as $input) {
        echo " <p class='driverAlert' > DRIVER </p> <img src='taxi.png'  width ='50' height='50'title='driver'> <span class='trip'> {$input['name']}, Age: {$input['age']} <br> Is planning to go to {$input['arriveLoc']} from {$input['departLoc']}<br>
         Leaves on {$input['departDate']} and returns on {$input['returnDate']} <br> Will drive up to: {$input['desiredNum']} people <br> <br></span> 
         ";
    }
}
?>
 </div>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="driverbtn"value="Driver">
<div id="driver">

<form action="index.php" id="driverForm" method="post" class="form-inline">
 <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="desireNum" name="desiredNum" placeholder="Number of potential riders">
  </div><br> <br>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div><br> <br>

  <div class="form-group">   
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age">
  </div> <br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="depart" name="departLoc" placeholder="Departure Location">
  </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="arrive" name="arriveLoc" placeholder="Destination Location">
  </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="departDate" name="departDate" placeholder="Depart Date">
  </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="returnDate" name="returnDate" placeholder="Return Date">
  </div><br> <br>


<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit"> <input class="btn btn-default" title="Clear page content"type="submit" name="clear" value="Clear">
</form>

<!-- Creates form for Riders -->
<div id="formData2" >
<?php
#FOR THE DRIVERS ONLY 

if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    $_SESSION['inputs2'] = array();
}
if (!empty($_POST['nameTwo']) && !empty($_POST['ageTwo'])  && !empty($_POST['departLocTwo']) 
    && !empty($_POST['arriveLocTwo']) && !empty($_POST['departDateTwo'])  && !empty($_POST['returnDateTwo'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['inputs'])) {
        // initialize the saved input session variable the first time
        $_SESSION['inputs2'] = array();
    }
    $_SESSION['inputs2'][] = $_POST;
    foreach ($_SESSION['inputs2'] as $input) {
        echo " <span class='tripTwo'> <p class='riderAlert' > PASSENGER </p> <img src='rider.png'  width ='50' height='50'title='rider'> {$input['nameTwo']}, Age: {$input['ageTwo']} <br> Would like to go to {$input['departLocTwo']} from {$input['arriveLocTwo']} on {$input['departDateTwo']} and return on 
         {$input['returnDateTwo']}  <br> <br></span> 
         ";
    }
}
?>
 </div>
 <input class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="riderbtn"value="Passenger">
<div id="rider">

<form action="index.php" id="riderForm" method="post" class="form-inline">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="nameTwo" name="nameTwo" placeholder="Enter Name">
  </div><br> <br>

  <div class="form-group">   
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="ageTwo" name="ageTwo" placeholder="Enter Age">
  </div> <br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="departLocTwo" name="departLocTwo" placeholder="Departure Location">
  </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="arriveLocTwo" name="arriveLocTwo" placeholder="Destination Location">
  </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="departDateTwo" name="departDateTwo" placeholder="Depart Date">
  </div><br> <br>

   <div class="form-group">

    <input type="date" class="form-control input-sm" id="returnDateTwo" name="returnDateTwo" placeholder="Return Date">
  </div><br> <br>


<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Submit"> <input class="btn btn-default" title="Clear page content"type="submit" name="clear" value="Clear">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#riderbtn').click(function()
    {
        $('#rider').toggle();
    });
</script>

 <!--- End of rider data -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#driverbtn').click(function()
    {
        $('#driver').toggle();
    });

</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

When the user submits the form, append the inputs to a session variable, and display all the saved values from the variable.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    $_SESSION['inputs'] = array();
}
if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['age'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['inputs'])) {
        // initialize the saved input session variable the first time
        $_SESSION['inputs'] = array();
    }
    $_SESSION['inputs'][] = $_POST;
    foreach ($_SESSION['inputs'] as $input) {
        echo "You are {$input['name']} and you are {$input['age']} years old.<br>";
    }
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age">
<input type="submit"> <input type="submit" name="clear" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how I can clear the data that went to the paged based on the click of a button. I can do this in js, but am trying to figure it out in php? @Barmar

Comment: If you want to do it without reloading, you have to do it in Javascript, not PHP.

Comment: <button id="clear" onclick="clear()"> Clear</button>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#clear").click(function()
 {
        $('#formData').empty();
 });
</script>

Comment: I have the above code, but when I click clear it clears the page, reloads then it comes up again. Thank you very much for all of you help @Barmer

Comment: Sorry, when I wrote the above comment I was thinking this was a different question. You need a form submission option that the PHP script uses to empty the session variable.

Comment: I've added a `Clear` button that does this.

Comment: Hello, may you take a look at the new updated code please? I have updated it to toggle the forms between two button using jquery, but am running into the issues explained above. Again, thank you for all of your help. @Barmar

Comment: You need to give the buttons different names in the driver and rider forms. Otherwise, when it does `if (isset($_POST['clear']))` it can't tell if it's the clear button from the rider or driver form.